# Poco c++/Sqlite with persistent capability

Tags: sqlite, poco, poco-libraries, persistent-storage

I am trying to find if any open resources available which implements persistent database capability like ObjectStore or Fast objects. Does Poco C++/Sqlite library provides options to have this capability? if not, is there any open source implementation available?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Poco supports in memory databases and you can use `fileToMemory`
https://pocoproject.org/docs/Poco.Data.SQLite.Utility.html#5848
and `memoryToFile`.
This has helped me use sqlite for much better performance when the file access got in the way.

Otherwise, there is https://pocoproject.org/docs/Poco.LRUCache.html which inherits from `AbstractCache` but I have not used it.

Comment: Thank you @Cookie Butter for your answer. What I see is: this utility loads the content of the DB from/to in-memory/file. I think I am looking for a solution where my C++ objects can be stored and retrieved from the DB as a persistent object. Lets say my application was shut down. When I restart, all those previous C++ objects which were stored into the DB should come back alive (restore). Similiar like what Object store or FastObjects DB provides for embedded applications.

Comment: oh I see.  I don't think Poco supports that but there are ways to save config data in the *Configuration classes.  I know it is not what you asked for.